# gather terms of expression

Tags: matrices

I have this equation:

\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{(x - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(x - \mu) + (\mu - \mu_0)^T S^{-1}(\mu - \mu_0)}
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{x, \mu, \mu_0}$ are vectors and $\mathbf{\Sigma, S}$ are symmetric invertible matrices. I am asked to expand and gather terms. So far I was able to expand and got:
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{x^T\Sigma^{-1}x - x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu - \mu^T\Sigma^{-1}x + \mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu +} \\
  \,\,\quad \mathbf{\mu^TS^{-1}\mu - \mu^TS^{-1}\mu_0 - \mu_0^TS^{-1}\mu + \mu_0^TS^{-1}\mu_0} \\
\end{align*}
Which I suppose I could rewrite as:
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{x^T\Sigma^{-1}x + \mu^T(\Sigma^{-1} + S^{-1})\mu - \mu^T(\Sigma^{-1}x + S^{-1}\mu_0) - (x^T\Sigma^{-1} + \mu_0S^{-1})\mu + \mu_0^TS^{-1}\mu_0}
\end{align*}
or as:
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{\mu^T((\Sigma^{-1} + S^{-1})\mu - \Sigma^{-1}x - S^{-1}\mu_0) + x^T \Sigma^{-1}(x - \mu) - \mu_0^T S^{-1}(\mu - \mu_0)}
\end{align*}

But it feel like both ways only complicate things and are not the intended way. How should I proceed?

Yes this is a homework question. If you could point me to a source where I can find out how to do this myself then that would be awesome, any other form of a hint would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you only need to expand the first expression of your post, then your second expression is fine. You will not be able to write something much better than this. Maybe you could provide more informations about *why* you want to expand the first expression. Once you expanded it, what will you do with it ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The question is threefold. (1) expand and gather terms. (2) Collect all terms that depend on $\mu$ and those that do not. (3) Take the derivative with respect to $\mu$ set to 0, and solve for $\mu$. I think that before I even try (2) or (3), I must do (1) properly. I could try to just factor out $\mu$ immediately, that would certainly make it easier to take the derivative, but I feel that I would be skipping something in (1) or (2) then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you expand, you can use the fact that $\mathbf{x}^{\top}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}\boldsymbol\mu$ and $\boldsymbol\mu^{\top}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{x}$ are the same. This follows from the symmetry of the inner product $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) \mapsto \mathbf{x}^{\top} \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{y}$. Therefore,

$$ (\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu)^{\top}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu) + (\boldsymbol\mu - \boldsymbol\mu_{0})^{\top} \mathbf{S}^{-1} (\boldsymbol\mu - \boldsymbol\mu_{0}) \tag{$\star$}$$

expands into :

$$ \underbrace{ \boldsymbol\mu^{\top} \big( \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1} + \mathbf{S}^{-1} \big) \boldsymbol\mu }_{(1)} - \underbrace{ 2 \boldsymbol\mu^{\top} \big( \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{S}^{-1}\boldsymbol\mu_{0} \big) }_{(2)} + \underbrace{\ldots}_{(3)} $$

where $(1)$ are terms which are *quadratic* in $\boldsymbol\mu$, $(2)$ are terms which are *linear* in $\boldsymbol\mu$ and $(3)$ are terms which do not depend on $\mu$. When you expand $(\star)$ (using bilinearity), you will always obtain quadratic and linear terms. Looking specifically for one or the other may help you instead of expanding and *then*, group the terms.

If you want to differentiate this quantity with respect to $\boldsymbol\mu$, define :

$$ f : \boldsymbol\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \boldsymbol\mu^{\top}\big( \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1} + \mathbf{S}^{-1} \big) \boldsymbol\mu - 2 \boldsymbol\mu^{\top}\big( \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1} \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{S}^{-1} \boldsymbol\mu_{0} \big) \in \mathbb{R}. $$

Differentiate $f$ and setting its differential equal to $0$ is the same as finding the *gradient* of $f$ and setting this vector to $0$. In order to find the gradient of $f$ at $\boldsymbol\mu$, remember that it is defined by :

$$ \forall \mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \; f(\boldsymbol\mu + \mathbf{h}) = f(\boldsymbol\mu) + \mathbf{h}^{\top} \nabla f(\boldsymbol\mu) + o(\Vert \mathbf{h} \Vert^2). $$

Then, again, identifying in $f(\boldsymbol\mu + \mathbf{h})$ the terms that are *linear* in $\mathbf{h}$ will give you the gradient of $f$.